# How can I fetch multiple JSON files from one directory in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch

This is a react project. I have a folder name data inside src where there are multiples JSON files. Now I need to fetch all the JSON files from data directory but the problem is I don't know the names of the JSON files so how can I fetch all of the JSON files from data folder in React?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through them you should create an index.ts file in your JSONs dir, and import all files in it, and export all of them as a single array that contains all the JSONs, and import it anywhere and do what you want.

index.js:

```
import file1 from './file1.json';
import file2 from './file2.json';

let items = [file1, file2];

export default items;
```

anywhere else in your app:

```
import items from 'URLS_DIR';
console.log(items, ` <--- items ----`); // iterate through them
```

[image: Files Dir]

Comment: When I try to import the jsonFiles from data directory it says - Module not found: Can't resolve './data'. The json files are inside data directory which is inside src folder. And when I try to keep the json files inside public folder and then write the above code you gave this shows me the error Attempted import error: './' does not contain a default export (imported as 'jsonFiles')

Comment: how are your JSON files?

Comment: JSON files are all inside data folder and the data folder is inside src. Inside data folder json files are like 2.json, 7.json, 13232.json, 3423.json like this.

Comment: updated the answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Promise.all" in order to await every single file as shown below. Use the method suggested by the answer above, and implement the code below as well in order to get the best result!

```js
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```